# Fade images in and out on a web page

Tags: javascript, fadein, fadeout

I wish to create an click-triggered image carousel, such as if you click on the button, an image fades in and when you click another button for the next option, the current image fades out and the a button image fades in.

An example of this web's can be found under Products and Services on the [GE-Energy website](http://www.ge-energy.com/) (scroll a bit down).

How could this effect be achieved?

Comment: simple ... using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)

Comment: how? i'm new to all this, do not know much about these things :$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This effect is achieved by using jQuery to fade the images out and in. In code this would be along the lines of:

```
$('#image1').fadeOut();
$('#image2').fadeIn();
```

And the HTML:

```
<img src="first_image.jpg" id="image1"/>
<img src="second_image.jpg" id="image2"/>
```

**Edit:**

This is the minimum JavaScript you would need in your HTML source:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#showfirst').click(function(e) {
        if($('#image1').css('display') != 'none') return;
        $('#image2').fadeOut();
        $('#image1').fadeIn();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('#showsecond').click(function(e) {
        if($('#image2').css('display') != 'none') return;
        $('#image1').fadeOut();
        $('#image2').fadeIn();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

And the following HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="showfirst">Show first image</a>
<a href="#" id="showsecond">Show second image</a>
<img src="first_image.jpg" id="image1"/>
<img src="second_image.jpg" id="image2" style="display:none"/>
```

Comment: hmmm, but then how to attach buttons which would work to make images fade in and out.

something like this, http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/examples/image-rotator/#

but i made my links not via lists, so how would I be able to the code to a tags inside p tags. ?

Comment: You could surround the images with `a` tags and trigger a javascript function when those tags are clicked.

Comment: Take a look at the [jQuery click documentation](http://api.jquery.com/click/). To replicate the functionality of the GE-Energy site you would probably have `a` tags elsewhere in the HTML document.

Comment: @Chaki I've added a sample implementation.